# Installing latest version of vsftpd on an ec2-linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ftp, vsftpd

I installed vsftpd on my Amazon ec2-linux AMI using `sudo yum install vsftpd`. However, it installs version 2.2.2.

How do I install version 3.0.2? I downloaded the tar file from https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html, extracted it, and followed the instruction from the INSTALL file. However, when I try to run the "make" command, it fails saying:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcap
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [vsftpd] Error 1
```

What is the problem? Is there any other way to get the latest version?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: How do I "move" it? Do I just repost?

Comment: You delete here and re-post there. But you cannot delete anymore as this question has an answer already. Instead, flag your post for a moderator attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the FAQ file in the tar file:

> Q) Help! vsftpd doesn't build, it fails with an error about being
>   unable to find -lcap.
>
> A) Install the libcap package and retry the build. Seems to affect Debian users a lot.
>
> A) Install the libcap-devel. This certainly affects Fedora.

Since Amazon Linux AMI is based on Red Hat, then probably you will need `libcap-devel`.